# Testing Multiple Array Elements

Tags: c, arrays

Trying to figure out how to write a program where it checks each element in the array to see if it’s:

1. Less than 65
2. Equal or more than 65 but less than 70
3. Equal or more than 70 but less than 80
4. Equal or more than 80 but less than 90
5. Equal or more than 90

I also have to then display how many of the elements fall into each category, but pretty sure I can figure that part out on my own.

At the moment I can’t think of any way to do test it aside from testing each element of the array individually but that doesn’t seem like it’s right.

The array is initialized like this:

```
double grades[3][6];
grades[0][0] = 55.0;
grades[0][1] = 65.0;
grades[0][2] = 72.0;
grades[0][3] = 77.0;
grades[0][4] = 80.0;
grades[0][5] = 90.0;

grades[1][0] = 99.0;
grades[1][1] = 65.0;
grades[1][2] = 70.0;
grades[1][3] = 71.0;
grades[1][4] = 87.0;
grades[1][5] = 81.0;

grades[2][0] = 66.0;
grades[2][1] = 53.0;
grades[2][2] = 69.9;
grades[2][3] = 89.9;
grades[2][4] = 81.9;
grades[2][5] = 103.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can’t think of any way to do test it aside from testing each element of the array individually

Yeah, if you find yourself done 1 task, that's exactly the same, over and over again, the odds are that you should have put in a loop.

The easiest way of testing each element in a multidimensional array like this is doing it wtih a nested for loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3, i++)
    for(int j = 0; j<6; j++)
    {
        if(grades[i][j] < 65)
           // do lt 65 stuff
        else if(grades[i][j] < 70)
           // do 65-70 stuff
        // ...
        else
           // do 90+ stuff
    }
```

Comment: Also, to minimize the comparisons performed, I would use an `else if` chain. As in `if(grades[i][j] < 65) ;` `else if(grades[i][j] < 70) ;`, etc. Once you've passed the first `if`, you already know it's `>= 65`, so there's no need to check that again.

Comment: @Mike Thanks both of you the program works really well with the loop.